# Some pictures aren't viewable within a browser - instead they want to be downloaded first

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser, opera

For example lets take the [images of this link](http://hddguardian.googlecode.com/svn/awards/). The first PNG can be viewed in Chome 24 or Opera 12 simply by clicking it.  But the third PNG can not be viewed with the browser. Instead both browsers want to download the image.

This also happens with JPG and other PNG files, not just with the example images above.

The strange thing is, that Internet Explorer 10 shows both images just fine.
Whats the reason behind this?

Used browsers

- Opera 12.13 *(tested with new profile)*
- Chrome 24 *(tested with new profile)*
- Internet Explorer 10

Comment: Firefox (at least the v.9.0.1 at my university library) does the same, except for all of them, except `main-window.png` and the text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. Links to the first two images use the same syntax and they both go to the same directory. They are both apparently valid png files (haven't verified that). But the googlecode server handles them differently. The first (that displays) it returns as type "text/plain".

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 30 Jan 2013 20:05:47 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Mon, 27 Feb 2012 15:02:40 GMT
ETag: "228//4star-oyksoft-plain.png"
Expires: Wed, 30 Jan 2013 20:08:47 GMT
Content-Length: 4549
Content-Type: text/plain
```

The 2nd (downloaded) is returned as "application/octet-stream".

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Last-Modified: Mon, 13 Aug 2012 12:54:41 GMT
Content-Length: 2330
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Wed, 30 Jan 2013 20:06:09 GMT
Server: Apache
ETag: "288//badge.png"
```

Apparently the browser tries to handle the text version, but punts on the application type and just downloads it ("Hey user, you figure it out").
So it looks like that server is returning different responses for some unknown reason.